# Find an irreducible polynomial in $ Q[x]$ of degree $726$.

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Find an irreducible polynomial in $ Q[x]$ of degree $726$.

I first thought of $x^{726}+1$ to start but its roots would be complex so not in $Q$.

Now I'm thinking to use Eisenstein, so taking the polynomial to be $f(x) = a_nx^{n} + b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...$ and finding an irreducible element p. However I'm not sure how I would assume p if I don't know anything else but the degree...

This is the first time I have seen a problem of this style so I do want to complete it myself however I would like to know if I am on the correct path.

Comment: $x^{726}+2$ is an easy example . With Eisenstein , you see immediate that it is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$

Comment: Note that no root can be in $\mathbb Q$, since the polynomial would then be reducible over $\mathbb Q$. But your example nevertheless does not work because $\ x^2+1\mid x^{726}+1\ $

Comment: Ok thank you both. What I'm struggling to think of is how you know what p to take when using Eisenstein. Is this just something I'm supposed to be able to picture? As at the moment I can't picture it!

Comment: @user22250987  It's true for any prime $p$ because $0$ is divided by $p$, but $p$ is not divided by $p^2$.

Comment: @user22250987 Actually, both comments are from me :)

Comment: I think you can write an answer. Or should I write one?

Comment: apologies @Peter! I know the theory for p but what I'm meaning is how do you know what to take as p? If there are many options for p, is it just a case of trial and error?

Comment: Thank you @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг that would be very appreciated if you could write one.

Comment: The insights for Eisenstein criterion are given by the finite extensions of p-adic numbers (uniformizer of totally ramified extension), but concretely you don't need those insights, just show that it works, $x^n \pm p$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{ Z}/(p^2)[x]_{monic}$ which implies that it is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ thus in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, we use Eisenstein's criterion. We deliberately construct a polynomial for which Eisenstein's criterion is satisfied. We could construct this for any prime, but we do it with $p=2$.

How? Well, Eisenstein requires two things :  all coefficients except the leading one should be divisible by $2$, and the constant coefficient should not be divisible by $2^2 = 4$. Multiples of $2$ are easy to find, and those which are not multiples of $4$ can also be found easily ($2$ is such an example). So, any polynomial satisfying this fits the bill. The polynomial $x^{726} +2$ is one such : all coefficients except the leading ($1$) are multiples of $2$ (almost all of those are $0$, so this is obvious), but $2$ is not a multiple of $4$. So Eisenstein applies and we have an example.

For another one : $x^{726} + 4x^{725} + ... + 4x^2+4x+2$ also qualifies.

Of course, switching $2$ for another prime can also be done.

---

> How to identify which prime to perform an Eisenstein on?

Well, the first thing to note is that Eisenstein may not even work for an irreducible polynomial. For example, Eisenstein won't work on $x^6+108$ (You can try to see why), even if I shift $x \to x\pm a$ for a constant $a$. However, it is irreducible.

Similarly,Eisenstein would not work on $x^4 + 4$. But then, nothing would work : in fact $x^4+4 = (x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$.

But when it does work, it comes in many ways : the most obvious from observing the constant coefficient.

Example : Show that $x^6 + 48x+24$ is irreducible.

Answer : $24$ is a multiple of $2$ but also of $4$, so you can't use $2$. You can use $3$ though : $24$ is not a multiple of $9$, and $48$ is a multiple of $3$. So things work out.

Another not-so-obvious one is from a shift. Also, usually while exhibiting something for a family of polynomials, you could use the index of the family. For an example of both these, for a prime, consider $x^p + x^{p-1} + \ldots + x+1$. It is irreducible after the shift $x \to x+1$, then applying Eisenstein for the prime $p$.

Sometimes there may be no link. For example, take $x^2+x+2$. It is irreducible after the shift $x \to x+3$ giving $x^2+7x+14$, which satisfies Eisenstein with $7$ although one would not have guessed this from the initial polynomial.

Finally, you can use the reversed polynomial technique. Any polynomial is irreducible if and only if the polynomial obtained by reversing the coefficients is irreducible. A reversed Eisenstein is possible, for this one observes the leading coefficient.

Let us take $2x^5-4x^2-3$. Clearly $4$ and $3$ are coprime, so right now you cannot apply Eisenstein. Reverse the coefficients : they are in the order $2,0,0,-4,0,-3$. After reversing, they would be in the order $-3,0,-4,0,0,2$ , giving the polynomial $-3x^5-4x^3+2$. This polynomial is Eisenstein with $2$, so is irreducible. One can then conclude that the latter is irreducible.

This tells you that when you are looking for a prime to do Eisenstein on, you must derive hints from a pattern (does it belong to a family?) , its middle and constant coefficients, or its middle and leading coefficients by reversal.

Comment: What a great and thorough explanation. Thank you so much for taking the time to write this.

Comment: You are welcome!